# Is for_each the only way to retrieve values from a Terraform set?

Tags: terraform, hcl

Terraform recently introduced the `set` datatype, described [on this page](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/types.html) as:

> `set(...)`: a collection of unique values that do not have any secondary identifiers or ordering.

It is difficult to find documentation on how to retrieve values from Terraform sets. With a map, you can index on the key:

```
password = var.passwords["kevin"]
```

With a list, you can index on the element number:

```
a_record = var.records[1]
```

However, I cannot use either of those methods to retrieve values from a set, even a set with only a single item.

In other places, the documentation mentions `for_each` as a method to get values out of a set.

```
variable "subnet_ids" {
  type = list(string)
}

resource "aws_instance" "server" {
  for_each = toset(var.subnet_ids)

  ami           = "ami-a1b2c3d4"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id     = each.key # note: each.key and each.value are the same for a set

  tags = {
    Name = "Server ${each.key}"
  }
}
```

Is the `for_each` meta variable the only way to access the values in a set?

Comment: Can you share how you've tried to access elements from a set and the errors you got from doing that? Normally you'd just cast it to a list and slice it.

Comment: ...which is not something I have ever seen before or had to do myself in my four years of Terraform, so this use case and that comment (hopefully soon answer) are both interesting to me. Other than that, i would have said "yes" to the question, except that `for_each` is not a meta variable (sorry to be pedantic).

Comment: Why would you say `for_each` is not a meta variable? https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#meta-arguments lists it as one of the meta arguments available for all resources although it's more complex than that as it also appears in `dynamic` blocks where the others are not (mostly because `dynamic` requires it).

Answer (score 43):

You can also slice a set by first casting it to a list and then accessing it as a list.

As an example:

```
variable "set" {
  type = set(string)
  default = [
    "foo",
    "bar",
  ]
}

output "set" {
  value = var.set
}

output "set_first_element" {
  value = var.set[0]
}
```

This will error because sets can't be directly accessed by an index:

```
Error: Invalid index

  on main.tf line 14, in output "set_first_element":
  14:   value = var.set[0]

This value does not have any indices.
```

If you instead cast it with the [`tolist` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/tolist.html) then you can access it as expected:

```
output "set_to_list_first_element" {
  value = tolist(var.set)[0]
}
```

```
Outputs:

set = [
  "bar",
  "foo",
]
set_to_list_first_element = bar
```

Note that this returns `bar` instead of `foo`. Strictly speaking sets are unordered in Terraform so you can't rely on the order at all and are only consistent during a single run of Terraform but in practice they are stable and in the the case of [`set(string)` they are sorted in lexicographical order](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/types.html#conversion-of-complex-types):

> When a set is converted to a list or tuple, the elements will be in an arbitrary order. If the set's elements were strings, they will be in lexicographical order; sets of other element types do not guarantee any particular order of elements.

The main place this comes up is if you are dealing with a resource or data source that returns a set type in Terraform 0.12 but need to use a singular value. A basic example might be something like this:

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "private" {
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id

  tags = {
    Tier = "Private"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "app" {
  ami           = var.ami
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id     = tolist(data.aws_subnet_ids.example.ids)[0]
}
```

This would create an EC2 instance in a subnet tagged with `Tier = Private` but set no other constraint on where it should be.

While you referenced being able to access values with `for_each` you can also loop through a set with a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions):

```
variable "set_of_objects" {
  type = set(object({
    port    = number
    service = string
  }))

  default = [
    {
      port    = 22
      service = "ssh"
    },
    {
      port    = 80
      service = "http"
    },
  ]
}

output "set_of_objects" {
  value = var.set_of_objects
}

output "list_comprehension_over_set" {
  value = [ for obj in var.set_of_objects : upper(obj.service) ]
}
```

This then outputs the following:

```
list_comprehension_over_set = [
  "SSH",
  "HTTP",
]
set_of_objects = [
  {
    "port" = 22
    "service" = "ssh"
  },
  {
    "port" = 80
    "service" = "http"
  },
]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing... it looks more awkward in the full example since it's calling tolist() in the middle of a larger variable, but it does the trick. This is helpful. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/25717

Answer (score 4):

In Terraform v0.15 and later, you can use `one` function.

If you have zero or one elements. thanks @Camilo Silva for the note

For example:

```
output "one_subnet" {
  value = one(data.aws_subnet_ids.public)
}
```

see https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/one.html

Comment: Don't use `one` with sets that might have more than one element. This function will fail in that case